# Angular js : How to clone form with reset value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I created a form with directives.

I want to clone this form add below the form. Max four time can be repeated this form. But stuck how clone works in angualr js.

html

```
        <form class="form-horizontal text-center" role="form" name="DTOstep1" ng-submit="onSubmit()">
            <div class="wrapDIV" id="wrapDIV">
                <div ng-repeat="que in questions[$state.current.name]">
                    <div ng-if="que.QuestionData._fieldType === 'text'" >
                        <text-control-dir data="que.QuestionData" default="{{PC}}"></text-control-dir>
                    </div>  
                    <div ng-if="que.QuestionData._fieldType === 'select'" >
                        <select-control-dir data="que.QuestionData"></select-control-dir>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-if="que.QuestionData._fieldType === 'radio'" >
                        <radio-control-dir data="que.QuestionData"></radio-control-dir>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-if="que.QuestionData._fieldType === 'hidden' && que.QuestionData._attributeName != 'CBQ'" >
                        <hidden-control-dir data="que.QuestionData"></hidden-control-dir>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Save" /><input type="button" name="formclone" value="Form Clone"  ng-click="appendClonedDiv()" />
        </form>
```

plunker with complete code

http://plnkr.co/edit/Op1QDwUBECAosPUC7r3N?p=preview

Comment: why do you need to clone it?  wrap it up inside another ng-repeat if that is possible?

Comment: I guess you're looking for https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/templates

Comment: Simple example with external html file :) https://plnkr.co/edit/pdUk7MPJASZtzO9fWDyR?p=preview